# Why do we require secondary indices in DBMS?

Tags: sql, database, rdbms

I get the point that primary indices are unique to each record and hence retrieving a record gets faster using primary indexing. What happens when we use secondary indexing.

Of what I can think of,

```
ID     Name     School
1      John      XYZ
2      Roger     XYZ
3      Ray       ABC
4      Matt      KJL
5      Roger     ABC
```

if we have secondary indexing on Name, then it will help me retrieve records relevant to names and not with id hence it would not restrict me to one record if I query a record for Roger and I would be able to get result pertaining to both Rogers. Hence if the table is extensively queried based on the secondary index, it should be used.

Am I right?

Comment: It speeds up access by `Name`, yes.

Comment: You won't really see a difference with `Name` being secondary indexed or not unless you have very large amounts of data. What the second index on `Name` does is when you say `WHERE Name = 'Matt'`, with Name being indexed, the database engine and instantly find and retrieve those records vs having to do a costly table scan. (in a nutshell)

Comment: `Why do we require secondary indices in DBMS?` - We don't.  There's nothing *requiring* the use of an index at all.  If you are doing a large number of queries on your tables for `Name`, it would make sense to add an index to that column to speed up those queries.  But there's nothing *requiring* you to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from speeding up specific queries, perhaps the most common case for secondary indexes is to speed up checking of UNIQUE constraints. Consider e.g. a table

```
CREATE TABLE Person (
    id               int primary key,
    fname            text not null,
    lname            text not null,
    date_of_birth    date not null,
    ...
    UNIQUE (fname, lname, date_of_birth)
)
```

Here we want to enforce the UNIQUE constraint to ensure the same person doesn't appear in the table multiple times under different ids. But at the same time we wouldn't want to make (fname, lname, date_of_birth) the primary key, because a person's name could potentially change, and because using 3 attributes as reference can be cumbersome.

Now, when inserting a new record into the table, the DBMS needs to check whether it already contains another tuple with the same (fname, lname, date_of_birth), and a secondary index on these attributes can help speed this check up.

Note that UNIQUE constraints automatically generate their indexes, so there is no need to create them explicitly.

Another common case where secondary indexes are required (and must be created explicitly) are foreign key constraints that target attributes that do not make up the primary key for the target table.